# Pivot text values in Oracle 21c

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Hello Can you please help me with this basic problem which for me become diffcult-
I just want to pivot the rows for the vendor and i m not able to do that.

This is my data set,just few rows-

```
  CREATE TABLE "PROB" ("VENDOR" VARCHAR2(26), "CATEGORY" VARCHAR2(26))

Insert into PROB (VENDOR,CATEGORY) values ('United co','bread');
Insert into PROB (VENDOR,CATEGORY) values ('United co','salt');
Insert into PROB (VENDOR,CATEGORY) values ('ali dist co','eggs');
Insert into PROB (VENDOR,CATEGORY) values ('ali dist co','meat');
Insert into PROB (VENDOR,CATEGORY) values ('ali dist co','yogurt');
Insert into PROB (VENDOR,CATEGORY) values ('marian srl','potato');
```

And this is the output:

```
United co   ali dist co  marian srl
bread         eggs        potato
salt          meat  
             yogurt
```

what i have tried but without look except with list_agg but I want everyting on multiple rows

```
  SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  VENDOR, CATEGORY
    FROM PROB
)
PIVOT (
    LISTAGG(CATEGORY, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CATEGORY)
    FOR VENDOR IN (
        'United co' AS United_co,
        'ali dist co' AS ali_dist_co,
        'marian srl' AS marian_srl
    )
);

select 
       max(case when vendor='United co' then category end) as  united_co,
   max(case when vendor='ali dist co'  then category end) as ali_dist,
       max(case when vendor='marian srl'  then category end) as marian_srl
from (select a.*,
row_number() over (partition by vendor order by category) as rn
      from prob a
     ) t
group by vendor, rn;

SELECT UNITED_CO, ALI_DIST, MARIAN_SRL
FROM (
    SELECT  VENDOR, CATEGORY, row_number() over (partition by vendor order by vendor) as seqnum
    FROM PROB
)
PIVOT (
    max(CATEGORY)
    FOR seqnum IN (1 AS UNITED_CO , 2 AS ALI_DIST ,3 MARIAN_SRL)
);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation, which is what you already tried but incorrectly (remove `vendor` from `group by` clause):

```
SQL> select
  2    max(case when vendor = 'United co' then category end) as united,
  3    max(case when vendor = 'ali dist co' then category end) as ali,
  4    max(case when vendor = 'marian srl'  then category end) as marian
  5  from (select vendor, category,
  6               row_number() over (partition by vendor order by category) rn
  7        from prob
  8       )
  9  group by rn;

UNITED                     ALI                        MARIAN
-------------------------- -------------------------- --------------------------
bread                      eggs                       potato
salt                       meat
                           yogurt

SQL>
```

Or pivot:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from (select vendor, category,
  3          row_number() over (partition by vendor order by category) rn
  4        from prob
  5       )
  6  pivot (max(category)
  7         for vendor in ('United co', 'ali dist co', 'marian srl')
  8        );

        RN 'United co'                'ali dist co'              'marian srl'
---------- -------------------------- -------------------------- --------------------------
         1 bread                      eggs                       potato
         2 salt                       meat
         3                            yogurt

SQL>
```

Comment: Littlefoot Thanl you for the help
Before putting this question i think for a hour a make searches to find other posts like mine but i did not find.
Thank you for taking time to help me